# Azure ACS multiply Return URLs for MVC WebAPI and Windows Store/Metro App

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, microsoft-metro, acs, windows-store-apps

I have setup ACS on Azure and enabled WIF on my MVC 4 site hosted on Azure. I also made a Windows Store App.

To be able to login from my windows store app i had to put this controller on the website to redirect the login to the webauthenticationbroker in the metro app.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post()
        {
            var data = this.Request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync();
            var test = data.Result;

            var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
            var identity = ((ClaimsIdentity)((ClaimsPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User).Identity);
            var token = data.Result["wresult"];

            response.Headers.Add("Location", "/api/federation/end?acsToken=" + "hello");

            return response;
        }
```

There is two problems.
1) I cant return the token to Metro because its to long. A big xml with claims. What is it i should send to my client?

2) When i use WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync - if i want to use the following url to login(it pops up and people can pick what provider to use) the return url needs to be set on the ACS management site. It need to point to my controller /mysite/federation/.

https://traffictheory.accesscontrol.windows.net:443/v2/wsfederation?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=/mysite/

and if i dont have this return url set to /mysite/ the authentication do not work on the mcv site.

I found one solution, setting the return url to /mysite/ and then in the windows store app i need to parse the identifiers myself.

```
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync("https://traffictheory.accesscontrol.windows.net:443/v2/metadata/IdentityProviders.js?protocol=wsfederation&realm=/mysite/&reply_to=/mysite/federation&context=&request_id=&version=1.0&callback=");
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

and pass a provider login to the authentication broker.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1, ACS supports a number of token formats, some of which are quite compact. I would recommend trying [JWT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185950.aspx#BKMK_3), which is in beta. You can also modify your output rules to decrease the number of claims in the token, which will make it smaller.

For 2, WS-Federation includes a "wreply" parameter, so you can add "&wreply=https://mysite.com/federation". Alternately, you can configure the "/federation" URL as the default reply URL for your RP in the ACS portal, in which case you don't have to specify it on every request.

Comment: You'll have to change the app to support it, but parsing a JWT is quite simple and there are existing online samples of JWT parsing like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179819.aspx) that help. SWT is also compact, and you may have an easier time finding code samples for it, especially if you're using WIF.

Comment: I managed to get the SWT token send to the client, but now i cant get the mvc site to accept the token when i make a request against the web api. It ends up in WSFederationAuthenticationModule.AuthorizationFailed no matter what i put in the authentication header :( Example of the token:

Comment: http%3a%2f%2fschemas.xmlsoap.org%2fws%2f2005%2f05%2fidentity%2fclaims%2fnameidentifier=HM81Sv2xnRD6P%2bm2W2T%2feBAfAhH2ZTMMxSBBOQ1Rxqs%3d&http%3a%2f%2fschemas.microsoft.com%2faccesscontrolservice%2f2010%2f07%2fclaims%2fidentityprovider=uri%3aWindowsLiveID&Audience=http%3a%2f%2f77.75.160.102%3a48451%2f&ExpiresOn=1348778300&Issuer=https%3a%2f%2ftraffictheory.accesscontrol.windows.net%2f&HMACSHA256=C7D9CvmEeGy1xHXFV3WqPn7L9Zm%2bwoXt8Z8IUf0tgmI%3d

Comment: WIF doesn't understand SWT by default, you need to add a SecurityTokenHandler for it. For an example of the configuration you need and a link to a handler, see [this link](http://zamd.net/2010/07/31/using-wif-for-securing-rest-service/).